# Swift Loading data from Firebase Collection and Subcollection Loop

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Here's a snapshot of my TableRepository.swift file. The portion commented out "//" — is where I'm really having a rough time. Anyone with experience in digging into a nested loop to query for a sub collection.

Ideally, trying to store data in a table array that also has a subcollection of lists.

Right now I can get it to connect and return "x" as the parent collection. But cannot seem to get the subcollection to load. Cheers for the peek at this.

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

// MODEL
struct Table: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    var title: String
    var sequencing: String
}

struct Row: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var rangeBegin: Int
    var rangeEnd: Int
    var rowContent: String
}

struct TableBuild {
    var table: Table
    var rows: [Row]
}

// TABLE REPOSITORY LOAD
class TableRepository: ObservableObject {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    @Published var tables = [Table]()
    @Published var rows = [Row]()
    
    init() {
        loadData()
    }

    func loadData() {
        db.collection("tablesTest").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
                self.tables = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                    do {
                        if let x = try document.data(as: Table.self) {
                            print("--- TABLE ---")
                            print(x)
                            
//                            self.db.collection("tablesTest").document(x.id!).collection("rows").addSnapshotListener { (queryRowSnapshot, error) in
//                                if let queryRowSnapshot = queryRowSnapshot {
//                                    self.rows = queryRowSnapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
//                                        do {
//                                            let y = try document.data(as: Row.self)
//                                        }
//                                        catch {
//                                            print(error)
//                                        }
//                                        return nil
//                                    }
//                                }
//                            }
//                            var tabild = [TableBuild]()
//                            tabild.append(TableBuild(table: x, rows: y))
//                            return tabild
                            
                            return x
                        }
                        
                    }
                    catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit / Additions:

Goal is akin to storing/updating data very similar to Peter Friese's https://github.com/peterfriese/MakeItSo/blob/master/final/MakeItSo/MakeItSo/Repositories/TaskRepository.swift — however, with the added complexity of needing to store data into a struct-like object that is 1) a Table with values of its own (title, meta, etc.) and 2) a series of Rows, each row with values of their own (content, sequence, etc.) — likely syncing data across devices in realtime.

Ideally the data would be stored locally / applied in this manner...

```
[Table 1]
- table title
- table other
- - [Row 1]
- - - row 1 content
- - - row 1 other
- - [Row 2]
- - - row 2 content
- - - row 2 other
- - [Row ...]
[Table 2]
- ...
```

Here's a snap of my

[image]

Comment: This function `db.collection("tablesTest").` loads all of the documents within that collection. Why are you loading them again `self.db.collection("tablesTest")` when they've already been loaded? e.g. the first time you load them you've got all of the documents within the querySnapshot. Can you more clearly describe what data you're after within those documents? Also, including an image of your Firestore structure may also help us to understand the question. Also, note `var tabild = [TableBuild]()` will execute before the code in the preceeding closure so `y` will likely be nil

Comment: @Jay thanks for the reply here. It was my understanding subcollections had to be handled entirely separately from their parents, thus the additional. I've added a bit more detail and a screenshot of the firebase setup here.

Comment: I added the image on your behalf. Links can break over time and if that happens, we won't know what the structure looks like. Also, good idea to get on the same page: Firestore has no rows, columns or tables. There are collections, documents and fields and they are different in behavior and structure. How your data is stored in Firestore is dependent on the queries you run against it. Can you clearly state, based on the image in your question, what data you want to get to within your tablesTest collection? For example *I want to iterate over each document within tablesTest and print the title*

Comment: @Jay understandable that there could be some confusion here... this app uses "tables" and "rows" within those tables. I understand that FS uses a format as... collections.documents.subcollection.documents... ultimately that's what I'm attempting to figure out is how best to loop through and get these subcollection documents out and into a table variable. That table would live inside an array of tables.

Comment: Understood. Please clarify what data you are trying to get to - that's the hard part. Taking that data in code and massaging it is the easy part.

Comment: @Jay needing to obtain the "table" document's title, and sequence (both string variables). After a single table is obtained, it should have its rows then also pulled down and stored. The rows in FS contain three variables: rangeBegin and rangeEnd (both Int), and then rowContent (String). — In an ideal scenario the rows would be stored within a key pair within a table... the table having its own simple variables as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to return the whole subcollection within a document from your parent collection. If so, you won't need to use a `addSnapshotListener` as this would be getting only one document, but rather, a `getDocuments()`. Your query would need to change to something for similar to the following.

```
db.collection("tablesTest").document(x.id!).collection("rows").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
        }
    }
}
```

**While this code is untested**, I believe it's a good starting point for you, as it shows how to get all documents from a collection, based in the official article [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection). After that, you just need to adapt it to your code, so it shows in the table as you would like. You can also get more information on how to work with subcollections on Firestore by checking the official tutorial [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections).

Comment: Thank you, @gso_gabriel, this is already very helpful. Will give this a go.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments the OP wants to get each document within `tablesTest` and access the `sequencing` and `title` fields. Also, they want to access the `rows` subcollection of each document for it's `rowContent` property.

Here's the code that does that

```
func readTables() {
    let tablesCollection = self.db.collection("tablesTest")
    tablesCollection.getDocuments(completion: { snapshot, error in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        guard let docs = snapshot?.documents else { return }
        
        for doc in docs {
            let seq = doc.get("sequencing") as? String ?? "No sequence"
            let title = doc.get("title") as? String ?? "No title"
            //print(seq, title) dont put this here
            tablesCollection.document(doc.documentID).collection("rows").getDocuments(completion: { rowSnap, error in
                if let err = error {
                    print(err.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                
                guard let rowDocs = rowSnap?.documents else { return }
                print(seq, title)
                for row in rowDocs {
                    let rowId = row.documentID
                    let content = row.get("rowContent") as? String ?? "No row content"
                    print("  ",rowId, content)
                }
            })
            
        }
    })
}
```

...and the output for two tables. The first table has two rows in it's rows subcollection and the second table has one row in its rows collection.

```
no sequence big table
   row_0 some content
   row_1 more content
sequential Another Table
   row_0 some content
```

Something to note: Firestore is asynchronous so the printing is done inside inner Firestore closure to ensure the var's 'stay together' when the data is returned. Otherwise, if the `print(seq, title)` were move outside of that closure, the printing sequence would be off depending on how fast the data was returned from the server.